# Get id's who caused DuplicateKeyError in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm using `insert_many` and I need to send a list of documents, and know which of those are duplicated.

My code raise the DuplicateKeyError, and I'd like to know if there are any field in the error that shows me the _id's it did not insert.

this is my code

```
 try:
     result = yield collection.insert_many(content, ordered=False)
 except DuplicateKeyError as e:
     print (e)
```

Traceback

> E11000 duplicate key error index: test.user.$*id* dup key: { : "4" }

Comment: where is  you code and the traceback?

Comment: It says *"dup key: { : "4" }"* right there

Comment: It only returns the last duplicated key it found. I need the list of duplicated keys.

Comment: @Tomalak To explain that it is "intended" that when using `ordered=False` and "many" inserts that such errors can occur "many" times, and otherwise complete any other operations in the batch. Only with `ordered=True` is the operation intended to throw an exception and "halt" on the "first" occurrence of any error.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error to inspect should be a [`BulkWriteError`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError) instead. This can potentially include more errors than the *"Duplicate Key Error"*, but of course you can always filter the results by the error code.

As a plain example ( since the returned classes are not dependent on the async API usage ):

```python
try:
   result = db.testme.insert_many([
    { "_id": 1 },
    { "_id": 2 },
    { "_id": 1 },
    { "_id": 3 },
    { "_id": 2},
    { "_id": [1] }
  ],ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError as e:
     pprint([err for err in e.details['writeErrors'] if err['code'] == 11000])
```

Which will return the duplicate key errors and the index positions in the source list at which they occurred:

```python
[{u'code': 11000,
  u'errmsg': u'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.testme index: _id_ dup key: { : 1 }',
  u'index': 2,
  u'op': {'_id': 1}},
 {u'code': 11000,
  u'errmsg': u'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.testme index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }',
  u'index': 4,
  u'op': {'_id': 2}}]
```

Of course the other error in there is because of trying to assign an "array" to the `_id` field, which is not allowed but also not a duplicate key error, so we filtered it:

```python
 {u'code': 2,
  u'errmsg': u"can't use an array for _id",
  u'index': 5,
  u'op': {'_id': [1]}}]
```

Comment: I tryed the `BulkWriteError` but the exception never got raised, I just got DuplicateKeyError. A partner wrote on txMongo forum and they found an error when the exception get raised you can see the fix in this link: [GitHub Fix](https://github.com/twisted/txmongo/pull/146/commits) but it still isn't released.

Comment: @JianLeón Nonetheless it is the correct way to do this regardless of the current implementation problem. If you are happy with the patch then I suggest you apply it to your own application dependencies. Using `BulkWriteError` is the correct and only way to do this since that is where the "array of errors" in an "unordered" batch is returned to. It is therefore a `txmongo` implementation bug. If you are not "tied" to twisted, then both `pymongo` and `motor` support other event loops and return the correct response type.